# Cannot cast from View to ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I can inflate two text views in one view in this manner and it works perfectly

```
(...)
v = this.minflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("Health");

tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
tv.setText(batHeal);
(...)
return v;
```

Now I need to inflate a expandableListView, but in line 2 I get "Cannot cast from View to ExpandableListView".

```
(1)v = this.minflater.inflate(R.layout.sensorlist, null);

(2)ExpandableListView sList = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.sList);
```

minflater is LayoutInflater get from getLayoutInflater()

sensorlist.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ExpandableListView 
android:id="@+id/sList"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Looks legit so far. More information is needed on what activity you are calling this from and how you are inflating the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most logical reason for this to occur would be that you have imported the wrong `ExpandableListView`. If you are using any external libraries or have created any packages that have their own `ExpandableListView` class, you could end up with something like the following;

```
import custom.somepackage.ExpandableListView;
...
ExpandableListView el = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.sList); 
// Above wont compile
android.widget.ExpandableListView el = (android.widget.ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.sList); 
// Above will compile.
```

On netbeans for example, it would be a very easy mistake to make to click the '**Create class "ExpandableListView" in package yourpackage.something**' suggestion, instead of clicking on '**Add import for android.widget.ExpandableListView**' suggestion.

I hope this is helpful. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Exactly, I was importing the list incorrectly. "import android.widget.ExpandableListView;" solve problem.